# Python script won't play sound as cgi, but via command line

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi

The CGI python script shown below, sound.py, plays a sound through a speaker connected to a Raspberry’s audio output. The sound plays fine when I execute the script from the command line via “python sound.py”.  However, when I try to trigger it as a cgi script by invoking it via the Web (http://192.168.1.246/cgi-bin/sound.py), the sound won’t play, and the browser will only display “Hi Hello World!”  (which, I suppose, indicates that the server at least recognizes it as a CGI script and executes it without producing errors).

I thought that the issue might have to do with the permissions/ownership of the sound file and tinkered around with those, but that didn’t help (I’m also pasting below information about the ownership and permission of the script itself, and the sound file).

Thanks a lot for helping!

Marc.

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root     root       441 Jul 10 23:23 sound.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root     root     29812 Jul  9 22:58 cardinal-short.mp3

Script (sound.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

import pygame

name = "cardinal-short"
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("/var/www/html/cgi-bin/cardinal-short.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(1.0)
while (pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True):
  continue
pygame.mixer.quit()

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print

print "Hi Hello World!"
```

Comment: If `pygame` won't initialize without X11 or a TTY, there's your problem. Logging your stdout and stderr to a file would be a good place to start.

Comment: Does the web server have audio hooked up? Are you expecting audio to play out of the web browser?

Comment: @user2357112 - not sure if the Web server has audio hooked up. How do I check this? I want the sounds to play from the Raspberry, not in the browser.

Comment: @Charles Duffy - thanks for this advice. Trying to get some logging going.

Comment: I was thinking of the machine serving the web requests, not the web server program; if it's the same machine (the Raspberry?) you were successfully running the script on from the command line, I'm not aware of any other audio setup you'd have to perform.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: trying to add logging as shown below. But it produced an internal server error ("End of script output before headers: sound.py"). Oops, can't paste the code here because it's too long.

Comment: Be sure to log to stderr, not stdout. You might also consider redirecting stderr to a file explicitly if you don't have easy access to your HTTP server's logs; for instance: `import sys; sys.stderr = open('/tmp/somefile', 'a')`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this via:

```
sudo usermod -aG audio www-data
```

and then restarting apache.

The problem was that, and I quote from [elsewhere](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=87353&p=615174) on the web:

> the sound devices (in /dev/snd/) are only accessible to members of group "audio". pi is a member of that group, and www-data is not.